# Scaling images to fit in a frame

Tags: beamer, graphics

I am trying to insert two images in a frame in `beamer`. The second image that I wish to add isn't fitting in the frame. Changing the `scale`value in `\includegraphics[scale=0.0005]{image/image.png}`doesn't fit the image in the frame. Any help would be appreciated[image: First image][image: Second image].

```
\documentclass[xcolor={table,dvipsnames,usenames}]{beamer}
\graphicspath{ {image/} }
\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.85}
\definecolor{LightCyan}{rgb}{0.88,1,1}
\newcolumntype{a}{>{\columncolor{NavyBlue}}c}
\newcolumntype{b}{>{\columncolor{white}}c}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{}
\begin{columns}
\column{1\textwidth}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{image/rabbit.png}
\caption{Steps }
\end{figure}
\column{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[scale=0.0005]{image/image.png}

\end{figure}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Edit: After updating the code

```
\documentclass[xcolor={table,dvipsnames,usenames}]{beamer}
\graphicspath{ {image/} }
\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.85}
\definecolor{LightCyan}{rgb}{0.88,1,1}
\newcolumntype{a}{>{\columncolor{NavyBlue}}c}
\newcolumntype{b}{>{\columncolor{white}}c}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{}
\begin{columns}
\column{.8\textwidth}% half of the width
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image/rabbit.png}
\caption{Steps }
\end{figure}
\column{0.2\textwidth}% half of the width
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[height=\textheight]{image/image.png}
\end{figure}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Instead of scale you could use the option width or height.

Comment: then try `height=.8\textheight` or `width=\textwidth`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first column is the width of the page, you must put it to its half `\column{.5\textwidth}` instead of `\column{1\textwidth}`

Instead of using `\includegraphics[scale=0.0005]` use `\includegraphics[height=\textheight]` or `\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]`

```
\documentclass[xcolor={table,dvipsnames,usenames}]{beamer}
\graphicspath{ {image/} }
\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.85}
\definecolor{LightCyan}{rgb}{0.88,1,1}
\newcolumntype{a}{>{\columncolor{NavyBlue}}c}
\newcolumntype{b}{>{\columncolor{white}}c}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{}
\begin{columns}
\column{.5\textwidth}% half of the width
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{image/rabbit.png}
\caption{Steps }
\end{figure}
\column{0.5\textwidth}% half of the width
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[height=\textheight]{image/image.png}

\end{figure}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1. Should that be `\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image/rabbit.png}` instead of `\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{image/rabbit.png}`?

Comment: Maybe, but since I don't know the dimensions of this image, I left it as is.

Comment: Please check the update in the original question. After making the changes that were suggested, the second image still occupies the space in which the title would be written. Is there a way to fit the second image so that it doesn't occupy the title space and also the space at the bottom right where the slide numbers would go.

Comment: +1 also for me. The rabbit is very beautiful and the code.