# Placing images in a frame- beamer

Tags: beamer, graphics

This is a follow up to my [previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/430129/scaling-images-to-fit-in-a-frame).I am trying to position 3 images in a frame in `beamer`.Two images have been placed side by side. I am trying to insert one more image at the bottom. Any suggestions on how this can be done?

```
\documentclass[xcolor={table,dvipsnames,usenames}]{beamer}
\graphicspath{ {image/} }
\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.85}
\definecolor{LightCyan}{rgb}{0.88,1,1}
\newcolumntype{a}{>{\columncolor{NavyBlue}}c}
\newcolumntype{b}{>{\columncolor{white}}c}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{}
\begin{columns}
\column{.5\textwidth}% half of the width
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image/rabbit.png}
%\caption{Steps }
\end{figure}
\column{0.5\textwidth}% half of the width
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image/rabbit.png}
\end{figure}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I wish to add one more picture at the bottom.
[image]

Comment: Can't you just put another `figure` with an `\includegraphics{}` after the `\end{columns}`. Your only difficulty will be lack of space: you will need to make sure the figure fits, or use `height` or `width` optional arguments to `\includegraphics` to make it do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

images are positioned by the same logic as letters so you just want one paragraph with two images side by side and another with a single image

[image]

```
\documentclass[xcolor={table,dvipsnames,usenames}]{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{}

\includegraphics[width=.47\textwidth]{example-image-a}\hfill
\includegraphics[width=.47\textwidth]{example-image-b}

\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=50pt]{example-image-c}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

A very simple solution using the *center* environment:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usetheme{default}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test images}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth]{rabbit.png}
\includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth]{rabbit.png}

\includegraphics[width=.47\textwidth]{rabbit.png}
\end{center}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: simple images positioning]

The "extrema ratio" solution: absolute positioning with *textpos* package:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usetheme{default}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos} %absolute positioning of text and graphic
\TPGrid[20mm,20mm]{20}{10}
\textblockorigin{3mm}{3mm}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test images}
\begin{textblock}{20}(16,0)
$(16,0)$\includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{rabbit.png}
\end{textblock}
\begin{textblock}{20}(6,5.5)
$(6,5.5)$\includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{rabbit.png}
\end{textblock}
\begin{textblock}{20}(-0.7,11)
$(-0.7,11)$\includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{rabbit.png}
\end{textblock}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: extreme image positioning]